# Linear interpolation of elements in a list to generate new list

Tags: interpolation

For a list of any given length, I want to generate another list from it adding elements which are mean of the consecutive elements, in between the elements, of the original list.
For example:

```
list = {a, b, c};
newlist = {a, (a+b)/2, b, (b+c)/2, c}
```

I have written this function which does the job but I need much more elegant solution:

```
intFunc[list_] := Module[{list1},
list1 = ConstantArray[0, 2*Length[list] - 1];
Table[list1[[2*i - 1]] = list[[i]], {i, 1, Length[list]}];
Table[list1[[2*i]] = (list[[i]] + list[[i + 1]])/2, {i, 1, Length[list] - 1}];
list1
];
```

Comment: This is not exactly what you want, but do you know ArrayResample? Try: ArrayResample[{a,b,c},5]

Comment: I added parentheses where I think you forgot to do so. Please correct me if I were wrong.

Comment: @MarkusRoellig I'll look into it.

Comment: @yohbs thanks for the correction

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
intFunc[list_]:=Interpolation[list, InterpolationOrder->1]@Range[1, Length@list, 1/2]
```

Comment: Looks good. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

My take:

```
list = {a, b, c};
Riffle[list, MovingAverage[list, 2]]
(* {a, (a + b)/2, b, (b + c)/2, c} *)
```

Equivalently:

```
MovingAverage[Riffle[list, list], 2]
```

Finally, can be generalized to multiple points in between original data points. Equivalent to previous solutions (if using `n=2`):

```
intList[list_, n_] := MovingAverage[Flatten[Transpose[ConstantArray[list, n]], 1], n]
```

Demo (offsets in data include for clarity):

```
list = {1, 4, 9};
ListPlot[Evaluate @ (#/2 + intList[list, #] & /@ Range[5]), DataRange -> {1, 3}]
```

[image: demo]

Re the comment by Markus Roellig: using `ArrayResample` like so gives the same results.

```
intList2[list_, n_] := ArrayResample[list, (Length[list] - 1)*n + 1]
```

Comment: Works well. Thanks.

Comment: @mrkbtr added an extension for multiple datapoints in between the original points, in case you might need that.

Answer (score 5):

For integer lists, this s/b nicely faster than others (interpolation and the two moving-average based solutions:

```
Riffle[#, Divide[Most@# + Rest@#, 2]] &
```

[image]

On real/symbolic, it is comparable to the moving-average based solutions. The interpolation based solution performs uniformly poorly on large lists regardless of type.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `Riffle[#, Divide...] &` rather than `Riffle[list, Divide...]&` ?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP oops, yes, fixing. Thanks for catching.

Comment: On my machine with a list of `4*^6` reals your solution still performs a factor of 2 better than the second best.